# How to count one by one how many files start with a word inside a folder (without using the os library)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, file, directory

This is my code, but it is missing the part where it counts the files, still try to use `startswith()` instead of regex, maybe it is a more direct solution in this case

```py
from pathlib import Path

def process_audio_files(file_name):

    #Edit the file
    transcription = file_name + "edited"
    
    return transcription
    

audio_chunks_path = "audio_chunks/"
names_structure = "chunk_"

#initializes the counter variable assuming that within the directory there may not be any files beginning with that word
n = 0
transcription = ""

if(audio_file.startswith(names_structure)): n += 1

#once all the files have been accounted for
for i in n:
   file_name = audio_chunks_path + names_structure + str(i) + ".mp3"
   
   transcription = process_audio_files(file_name)
   print(transcription)

   Path(file_name).unlink() #delete this chunk audio file
```

For this `for` loop to work I must know what the value of n is, and for that I must know how many files are inside that directory, and therein lies the problem.

In the directory there is an unknown number of files that start with that word, so the value of the variable `n` will also be unknown

```
audio_chunks/chunk_0.mp3
audio_chunks/chunk_1.mp3
audio_chunks/chunk_2.mp3
...
audio_chunks/chunk_n.mp3
```

Comment: There is the "glob" module with the "glob" function.

Comment: @MichaelButscher You can also use glob in Pathlib

Comment: I try with `n = Path("audio_chunks").glob("chunk_*.mp3")`, but i can't get the number of files that I need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to count the number of files, you can do:

```
n = sum(1 for _ in Path("audio_chunks").glob("chunk_*.mp3"))
```

However, if you want to find the files and delete them you can just use the same glob function and do something like:

```
for chunk_file in Path("audio_chunks").glob("chunk_*.mp3"):
    transcription = process_audio_files(chunk_file)
    print(transcription)
    chunk_file.unlink()
```

Comment: I have a problem when there is more than one number, for example "audio_chunks/chunk_10.mp3" or "audio_chunks/chunk_200.mp3"

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I didn't say anything, it was another error, there I checked that the operator * covers all the characters, really thanks for the help!